# Swift specific imports still import the entire module?

Tags: swift, import

Ran into some interesting behavior in the Swift REPL:

```
  1> import var Glibc.M_PI 
  2> M_PI
$R0: Double = 3.1415926535897931
  3> M_E
$R1: Double = 2.7182818284590451
  4>
```

According to the [language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351), only the symbol `M_PI` should be available when I do this import!

> #### Import Declaration
>
> An import declaration lets you access symbols that are declared outside the current file. The basic form imports the entire module; it consists of the import keyword followed by a module name:

```
import module
```

> Providing more detail limits which symbols are imported—you can specify a specific submodule or a specific declaration within a module or submodule. When this detailed form is used, only the imported symbol (and not the module that declares it) is made available in the current scope.

```
import [import kind] [module].[symbol name]

import [module].[submodule]
```

But instead, `M_E`, `sqrt()`, `sin()`, `log()`, and the kitchen sink are now running around in the scope. How do I prevent all those other symbols from getting imported?

Strangely, this only happens in the Swift console; compiled Swift code doesn’t do this.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how do i prevent the entire module from getting imported?

Comment: If it only happens in the playground, why does it matter?

Comment: the swift REPL is analogous to the Python console, surely it's just as important?